# Xilinx Vivado schematic for if else statements

Tags: if-statement, system-verilog, xilinx, vivado, synthesis

I am learning SystemVerilog. While coding, the synthesis schematic for the following `if` statements don't make sense to me.

```
module ifelseDUT(
input logic sela, selb, selc, da,db,dc,
output logic dout
    );
    
    always @*
    begin
        dout = 0;
        
      priority  if(sela)
            dout = da;
        if(selb)
            dout = db;
        if(selc)
            dout = dc;

        
    end
    
endmodule
```

Here is the synthesized schematic:

[image: priority if schematic]

How to understand the schematic when `sela` is not used? I am also not able to make sense of `S=default` value on the muxes.

Here is the message generated by Vivado. There are no errors or warnings during the synthesis.

```
[Synth 8-293] found qualifier priority on case statement: implementing as full_case ["C:/Users/homealien/Xilinx/ifelse-test/ifelse-test.srcs/sources_1/new/ifelseDUT.sv":32]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `priority if` statement does not contain an else clause, synthesis is treating it as:

```
if(sela)
   dout = da;
else
   dout = 'x; // don't care
```

and that is being optimized as just

```
dout = da;
```

This is because the `priority` is an assumption/assertion that a conditional branch will always be taken. Without an `else` clause, synthesis is generating logic assuming the condition is always true. This should have been caught as a synthesis error, but it is a legal description.

What you probably intended is:

```
always_comb
      priority if(sela)
            dout = da;
      else if(selb)
            dout = db;
      else if(selc)
            dout = dc;
      else
            dout = 0;
```

Now you have written the code is such a way that a conditional branch statement will always be taken under all possible conditions.

Comment: why does da has to go through first mux? Why there are two muxes? Should not there be one mux who select line is sela and i1 tied to da and i0 tied to X?

Comment: @tulamba No. X is a _don't care_ and optimization has decided that make `da` the other input to the third mux which eliminates the need for that mux. I know it does not make much sense, but that is because you used the `priority` construct incorrectly.

Comment: how to use` priority` construct correctly? Just put an` else`?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 12.4.2 *unique-if, unique0-if, and priority-if*

> If the keywords unique or priority are used, a violation report shall
> be issued if no condition matches unless there is an explicit else.

Since you have no `else` with the `priority if`, the Cadence simulator generates a warning.  Perhaps the Vivado simulator did as well.  Check your log files.

You likely want an `if/else` statement rather than 3 separate `if` statements:

```
module ifelseDUT(
input logic sela, selb, selc, da,db,dc,
output logic dout
    );
    
    always @*
    begin
        dout = 0;
        if (sela) begin
            dout = da;
        end else if (selb) begin
            dout = db;
        end else if (selc) begin
            dout = dc;
        end
    end
    
endmodule
```

Your problematic Verilog code results in a schematic with problems.

This Verilog code should fix the schematic problems.

---

> I am also not able to make sense of `S=default` value on the muxes.

To find out what `S=default` means on the schematic, read the Vivado documentation, contact Vivado for support or ask on a Vivado forum.